# How to organize a collection of demo web application

Tags: asp.net, windows, demo

I would like to create and archive a collection of demo ASP.NET web form applications that show projects with certain features in the sense "this feature can be implemented like this" -- to be presented to a potential customer.

Before the presentation, I would like to get the selected set of demo and install them easily to the notebook. Each of the demos will be "frozen". The target notebook is **not** the customer's one. It is one of our ones that is bring to the customer for the presentation. This way, it can be prepared in the sense that a named MS SQL instance with the fixed name can be ready, etc.

Can you share some experience with such situation? (I do not want to have marked this question as of *opinionated*; so please, if you have some explicit links to the related documents or explicit suggestions...)

Here are some other facts and initial ideas:

- Each of the demo projects uses two databases: `xxx_users` (the standard ASP.NET authentication...), and `xxx_application` (and possibly `xxx_external`) where `xxx` is a prefix for the specific project.
- The demo application is expected to be compiled (binary only, no sources needed for the presentation).
- The `Web.config` files can use the `local\SQLINSTANCEFORDEMOS` in connection strings.
- The SQL instance has a fixed name, fixed administrator account (like `sa`) and fixed password for the logging to the SQL instance. This way, it can be included in the `Web.config` files.
- The sample data can be fairly big (not extremely tiny).
- The application will use its own SQL tables in the `xxx_application` database.
- The application will simulate the outer database that is accessed from the web application can be simulated by `xxx_external` database.

This way, I should be able to create and archive SQL backups of `xxx_users`, `xxx_application`, and `xxx_external` databases, plus the archive of the web app binary.

Have you ever encountered this situation? Is the approach reasonable? Could you share some better ideas?

Comment: Applications are customization of the same product or not? Why do you talk about web form and then the post is marked by Windows tag?

Comment: @Emanuele: No, the opposite. The applications are anonymized real solutions that use various "tools" needed by the customers. The purpose is to show the customer how certain problem can be solved. Think in term _building blocks_ from the user point of view. The Windows tag is important as the solutions are designed to be used on Windows platform. The two ASP.NET main approaches to web application are webforms and MVC. All of this may or need not be related to the solution of the problem.

Comment: So you are imaging a web application to collect Windows application using some sections of existing code? I think it's impossible. You can record a video of that functionality.

Comment: @Emanuele: No. I want to have a collection of several full applications that will be used to show their different parts that can finally be combined into a new application. The goal is only to find the way how to keep our internal repository in the form that allows easy installation of the chosen set of application to the chosen computer that will be used for the presentation.